# My eclipse tomcat server is stopping and gives these exceptions "java.net.SocketException" and "java.net.BindException"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts, myeclipse

My eclipse tomcat server is stopping and gives these exceptions "java.net.secketException" and "java.net.BindException"
this is the console

```
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Users\k2b\AppData\Local\Genuitec\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\bin;C:\Users\k2b\AppData\Local\Genuitec\Common\plugins\com.genuitec.eclipse.easie.tomcat.myeclipse_8.6.0.me201007231647\tomcat\bin
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketListen(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.listen(PlainSocketImpl.java:374)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:320)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1059)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: listen failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 297 ms
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:33 PM org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin initDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:33 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml'
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:33 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml'
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml'
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin initDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml'
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources
INFO: Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml'
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:515)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1719 ms
2 Sep, 2013 5:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:590)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

In my system , i disable the "k7 security system" it is working fine. But some virus was attack my system. Please any one help for solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the last stack in the logs and you find the root cause of your problem:

```
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

It means there is already a process running and listening on the port you try to use.
Most of the time, this error is caused by a previous run of your own program that didn't terminate (properly), or is still running.

Take a look in your IDE to see if you don't have some running instance alive (and kill it).
You can also take look at running process under Windows task manager (or any other equivalent utility on other platforms) and try to identify the process using the port.

You may also have a tomcat running as a window service: in this case, just change the port use by your program to avoid conflicts.

Comment: @b3n75 i found both "myeclipse tomcat" and "K7 total security" had 8080 port numbers. i change the tomact port number to 2020. but it is not working

Comment: Your tomcat needs multiple ports: the offending one is 8005. You can configure it in server.xml.

Comment: That's what I mean: change it and restart your tomcat. The port 8005 is the default shutdown port for tomcat. It is used by control scripts to shutdown tomcat properly. (i.e. this is not the port used for "normal" http communication)

Comment: @b3n75 i have one more doubt, my system has multiple myeclipse workspaces, there is any problem for creating the multiple workspaces ?, please tell me

Comment: If it works : please accept the answer. Regarding multiple eclipse workspace... I don't know (I'm using IntelliJ). What I know is that "I'm using eclipse" and "I have problems with my IDE" are 2 sentences that often came together.